# Xcode 6 crash on UI debug

Tags: xcode

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1 on Mavericks and experiencing crash every time I try to inspect UI and:

1. unfold the view hierarchy
2. rotate the 3D inspection view

But it's not just crash. It literally restarts my Macbook Pro.

Comment: I cannot even get Xcode 6 to start under 10.9.  It's a disaster.

Comment: I've got similar crashes when using the view debugger... on rotation also.

Comment: Same issue here. I just avoid using the new Debug View Hierarchy. It crashes when I try to move the 3D view. My Mac restarts. I have a MacBook Air Early 2011, Mavericks 10.9.5 Xcode 6.0.1.

Comment: Yep, me too. MacBook Pro (early 2009), 10.9.5, Xcode 6.0.1 hard resets after doing anything useful with the UI debugger. Using the disclosure triangles works, but clicking anything else and I get a gray screen of death. Has been like that since the first beta I tried (3 or so).

Comment: Same here with Mavericks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bug for new Xcode with old System Maverick. I install new Yosemite and all working on my MacBook 2009.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I was able to narrow it down to an issue with the discrete graphics card on my Macbook Pro (it has the hybrid integrated Intel / discrete Nvidia chips). When forcing my Macbook Pro to use the integrated Intel chip exclusively, it no longer crashed.

You can get [gfxcardstatus](https://gfx.io/) to force your Mac to use the integrated chip exclusively.

If you use Homebrew Cask,

```
brew cask install gfxcardstatus
```

and then select 'Integrated only' from the app's menu bar icon before inspecting the UI.